# How to Resolve Netlify Error 'Install Dependencies'?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, netlify

I'm trying to upload a website made with react and typescript, but when I'm on the site to deploy it I have an error during the initialization phase:
[image: Error Relatory]
[image: Error]

I don't know why is this happening, just started into react 2 months ago and that's my first time upping a site. My gitignore archive have just 'node_modules', maybe is linked to that error?

Here's the entire repository: [text](https://github.com/ArthurZanolo/andretamiao)

Comment: https://github.com/ArthurZanolo/andretamiao text link*

Comment: Unrelated to answering your question -- you should NOT commit the `node_modules/` to your repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Granted, the info is elusive and hard to read, but this log basically explains  why the error is happening

```
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: typescript@4.9.5
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1 || ^4" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!     react-scripts@"5.0.1" from the root project
```

This indicates that `react-script` `v5.0.1` has a dependency of the `typescript` version of either a higher minor/patch version than 3.2.1, or a higher minor/patch version than 4. But in your `package.json`, it has `typescript` with the version of `^5.2.2`, consequently causing conflict and therefore throwing error.

To solve this, you can simply downgrade the `typescript` to the lower version, such as `4.9.5` by

1. running `npm i typescript@4.9.5`,
2. Check `package.json` if `typescript` is properly updated
3. test locally,
4. commit,
   5.and finally push.

In case the above fails, remove the `node_modules/` directory and `package-lock.json` and run `npm i` again.

BONUS POINT -- add `/node_modules` into your `.gitignore` file!!!